# issue with adding alias menu pointing to an external link

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla3.8

I'm having a problem,

usually when we want to point to an article with a direct link, and not show it in a menu, we use Hidden-menu feature, then we choose an alias, let's say:

```
secretpage
```

then we link an article to it,

and finally you can access that article with this direct link:

```
www.mywebsite.com/secretpage
```

this works perfectly, now we need to do the same, but instead of pointing the alias to an article made in joomla, we need to point it to an external link, exactly an office form (forms.office.com).

what I tried to do, is:

```
-hidden menu -> new

-menu item type: System links -> URL
```

and finally:

link: `https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

so when I navigate our website:

```
www.mywebsite.com/alias
```

what I get in return is

```
404 component not found joomla
```

any idea why this isn't working? 
I think joomla is appending my external link to:

```
www.mywebsite.com/external-link
```

and if that's the case, how to fix this?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing it as a redirect in the htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /alias https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

You could also find the broken url (https://www.mywebsite.com/alias) in the Redirect Manager and set it there instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. URL menu item type is not meant to redirect. It only shows an external link in menu module.